# Add an "abstract" method to (an F#) record

Tags: f#, record, abstract, c#-to-f#

I have created the following record in an attempt to translate a C# class to F#:

```ml
    type Days = Days of int
    type Value = Value of int
    type Item = {
        Name: string
        Expires: Days
        Value: Value
    }
```

Thing is I also need every Item to have a... "way", to run another function, yet not defined, `handleDevalue`, which acts on the item itself to manipulate the item's `Value` value.

The `handleDevalue` function is dependent on the `Expires` property of the item and thus each item's implementation of it would be different, with the only common thread being the function's name and signature (`Item -> Item`).
On the C# code I'm translating this method was defined as `abstract` on the `Item` class and overriden on every item instantiated (where every item is a subclass inheriting from `Item`).

What I've tried, *unsuccessfully* till now:

1. Add an abstract method on the record: `...} with abstract handleDevalue: Item -> Item`.
   1.1 *Reason for failure*: IDE tells me "abstract can't be added here as an augmentation" (or something close to the same effect). (I'm not F#-savvy enough to even know what it means, but the compiler won't let it compile so... no).
2. Add `handleDevalue` as a function on the record: `{... HandleDevalue: Item -> Item...}`.
   2.1. *Reason for failure*: this function is dependent on the `Expires` property. Apparently a record's fields are mutually independent of each other, and besides... how will the function "know" which item to act on (it's supposed to act on the item itself)? The `this` keyword is not allowed when implementing a function when "instantiating" a record (i.e. no `{...handleDevalue = fun this -> <some implementation code here>`).
3. I could remember to define the function on every item I create (I should anyway), but that's not using the type system to my advantage.
   I want the compiler to force me to implement the function and remind me if I don't.

With these ways failing I'm out of ideas how to move forward.

Thanks for any advice in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [interfaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/interfaces)? You can add interfaces to records by doing `type Record = { A : string; B : string } with interface IFoo with member this.FooImpl() = sprintf "%s: %s" this.A this.B`. (With appropriate indentation). Then anywhere you need to call `HandleDevalue`, you have to explicitly cast the record to an `IHandleDevalue` instance (F# deliberately doesn't do implicit casting, even to interfaces) like `(someItem :> IHandleDevalue).HandleDevalue()`. If you need more details, I'll turn this into an answer.

Comment: @rmunn this doesn't solve the problem. The problem is that different instances of `Item` need to have different implementations of the function.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - I thought it couldn't possibly be that different *instances* need different implementations, or how would the C# version have worked? I figured he had different subclasses. But apparently it was different instances needing different implementations after all. Weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about what actually happens in the C# program.

You have several different implementations of `handleDevalue`, and every item instance has one of those implementations associated with it. But what determines which one goes with which item? Well, this is determined by the specific descendant class that the item is. Ok, but what determines which descendant class gets instantiated?

Somewhere, at some point, there must be a place that picks a descendant class somehow. Let's assume it looks something like this:

```
class Item { public abstract int handleDevalue() { ... } }

class FooItem : Item { public override int handleDevalue() { ... } }

class BarItem : Item { public override int handleDevalue() { ... } }

public Item createItem(string name, Days expires, Value value) {
    if (foo) return new FooItem(name, expires, value)
    else return BarItem(name, expires, value)
}
```

So, look what's happening: ultimately, *whoever creates the items is choosing which `handleDevalue` implementation ends up being used*, and then that implementation gets attached to the item instance via the method table.

Now that we know this, we can do the same thing in F#. We'd just need to make attaching of the implementation explicit:

```
type Item = {
    Name : string
    Expires : Days
    Value : Value
    handleDevalue : Item -> Item
}

let handleDevalueFoo item = ...
let handleDevalueBar item = ...

let createItem name expires value = {
    Name = name
    Expires = expires
    Value = value
    handleDevalue = if foo then handleDevalueFoo else handleDevalueBar
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but I'll give it a shot.

Why not do something similar to this, using a discriminated union instead of inheritance?

```
type Days = Days of int
type Value = Value of int
type Item = {
    name: string
    expires: Days
    value: Value
}
type ItemType =
| FooItem of Item
| BarItem of Item
| BazItem of Item
// ...
let deValue item =
    match item with
    | FooItem i ->
        {
             name = i.name
             expires = i.expires -1
             value = i.value -1
        } |> FooItem
    | BarItem i ->
        {
             name = i.name
             expires = i.expires -1
             value = i.value -10
        } |> BarItem
    | // etc
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.

What I'm doing is converting a C# class which has an `abstract` `handleDevalue` method since each item will behave differently.

With regards to your proposed solution, I did try something of sorts but using Active Patterns to match on the item's properties.

I hoped, still do, that there is some way to put an abstract property on an F# record because matching the `Item`s is, as your code shows, very lengthy and feels not very idiomatic.

Thanks again for replying.

Comment: NP. Though, pattern matching like above is very much idiomatic in F# (as opposed to C# naturally). If this was production code and not an example, I could write it much less lenghty, but that would distract here.

Comment: I think (have not checked) that the problem with your code is that you defined `Item` as a record. In order to use abstract methods it must be a class.

Comment: You can pattern match over records too. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/records#pattern-matching-with-records